# Finding min and max date of overlapping date ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to write a query for below problem.

I want min start date time and max end date time of overlapping date ranges and same start & end date time for not overlapped date ranges in SQL Server

Example:- My_table

| NAME | Start Date Time | End DAte time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:30 | 01-02-2020 06:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 08:30 | 01-02-2020 09:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:55 | 01-02-2020 07:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 14:55 | 01-02-2020 18:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 13:40 | 01-02-2020 15:30 |
| Ram | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |
| Ram | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |

Expected result will be :

(*minimum and maximum time between all overlapped and not overlapped write as it is*)

| NAME | Start Date Time | End Date time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:30 | 01-02-2020 07:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 08:30 | 01-02-2020 09:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 13:40 | 01-02-2020 18:30 |
| Ram | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |

- **First row** of Result Values has overlapped date ranges so we right min and max of that all overlapped date ranges of that Name.
- **Second row** has no any overlap so we write it as it is ..
- **Third row** is overlapping so we write min and max of overlapped dates of Aman.
- **Fourth row** is also overlapping so we right it once with min and max date range.

Comment: If `Aman` had 2 more rows that overlap with each other, but not with any of the current rows for `Aman`, would the expected result then contain 2 rows for `Aman`?

Comment: Or are you looking for the single longest period for each name by grouping the overlapping sections?

Comment: @Sander . . . I think the question is quite clear.  The OP wants *overlapping* time ranges.  So if there were multiple unoverlapping ranges for Aman, then each would have its own row.

Comment: If you tried this for "5 days" then what did you try during those 5 days? At least show us your attempts as you may very well be close to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical gaps&islands problem, if you look around you will find many answers.

The following is an "old school" approach (least performant, since the table is accessed multiple times), which is a bit easier to follow (it assumes that enddatetimes are inclusive: if an enddatetime = with a startdatetime then there is an overlap):

```
declare @t table(name varchar(20), startdatetime datetime, enddatetime datetime);

insert into @t(name, startdatetime, enddatetime)
values
('Aman', '20200102 08:30', '20200102 09:30'),
('Aman', '20200102 04:40', '20200102 05:30'),
('Aman', '20200102 04:55', '20200102 07:30'),
('Ram', '20200102 04:40', '20200102 05:30'),
('Ram', '20200102 04:40', '20200102 05:30'),
--
('x', '20200102 02:40', '20200102 03:30'),
('x', '20200102 03:30', '20200102 04:55'),
('x', '20200102 04:20', '20200102 05:35'),
('x', '20200102 05:35', '20200102 06:42'),
('x', '20200102 06:00', '20200102 08:15');

select s.name, s.startdatetime, e.enddatetime
from
(
--starttimes which do not overlap start an island
select a.name, a.startdatetime, row_number() over(partition by a.name order by a.startdatetime) as rownum
from @t as a
where not exists (select * from @t as b where b.name = a.name and b.startdatetime < a.startdatetime and b.enddatetime >= a.startdatetime)
group by a.name, a.startdatetime
) as s --start datetimes
join
(
--endtimes which do not overlap, end an island
select a.name, a.enddatetime, row_number() over(partition by a.name order by a.enddatetime) as rownum
from @t as a
where not exists (select * from @t as b where b.name = a.name and b.startdatetime <= a.enddatetime and b.enddatetime > a.enddatetime)
group by a.name, a.enddatetime
) as e --end datetimes
on s.name = e.name and s.rownum = e.rownum;
```

Comment: Sir, thank you soooo much .. you solved my problem..  it is working perfectly .. you are great sir ..

Comment: @Nishant - please mark the answer as correct - as well as rewarding the person who took the trouble to give you a dig out, you are also helping those who have the same problem into the future!

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  name VARCHAR (20),
  start_date_time DATETIME,
  end_date_time   DATETIME
);
```

and then ran:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
('Aman',  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 08:30', 120),  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 09:30', 120)),
('Aman',  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 04:40', 120),  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 05:30', 120)),
('Aman',  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 04:55', 120),  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 07:30', 120)),
('Ram',   convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 04:40', 120),  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 05:30', 120)),
('Ram',   convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 04:40', 120),  convert(datetime, '01-02-2020 05:30', 120));
```

Then I ran the query:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  MIN(start_date_time) AS "Min dt", 
  MAX(end_date_time) AS "Max dt"
FROM test
GROUP BY name;
```

Result:

```
name                     Min dt                    Max dt
Aman    2020-01-02 04:40:00.000   2020-01-02 09:30:00.000
Ram     2020-01-02 04:40:00.000   2020-01-02 05:30:00.000
```

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6c61de7707d5deb719475dcaf7d397d2). In future, could you please construct your own fiddle using the site. This helps eliminate duplication of effort on behalf of those trying to help you and also removes the likelihood of errors! I ran some additional testing - see fiddle!

Comment: bro its not giving desired output please review the question , i added more information about problem.