# Minimum and maximum date of all overlapping date ranges of that particular name only in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want Min start date time and max end date time of overlapping date ranges and same start & end date time for not overlapped date ranges in SQL Server

Example:- My_table

| NAME | Start Date Time | End DAte time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:30 | 01-02-2020 06:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 08:30 | 01-02-2020 09:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:55 | 01-02-2020 07:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 14:55 | 01-02-2020 18:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 13:40 | 01-02-2020 15:30 |
| Ram | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |
| Ram | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |

**Expected result will be only overlapped date and time:**

(*minimum and maximum time between all overlapped date ranges*)

| NAME | Start Date Time | End Date time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 04:30 | 01-02-2020 07:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 08:30 | 01-02-2020 09:30 |
| Aman | 01-02-2020 13:40 | 01-02-2020 18:30 |
| Ram | 01-02-2020 04:40 | 01-02-2020 05:30 |

First row of Result Values has overlapped date ranges so we right min and max of that all overlapped date ranges of that Name Column only.

Second row has no any overlap so we write it as it is.

Third row is overlapping so we write min and max of overlapped dates of Aman.

Fourth row is also overlapping so we right it once with min and max date range.

Comment: Why did you create a new account and posted the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263407/finding-min-and-max-date-of-overlapping-date-ranges-in-sql-server? You could have edited the original question to clarify.

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag here, as you explicitly say you are using SQL Server. Also, what version are you really using, you tagged both 2008 (which has been End of Life for over a year) and 2012. Finally, what have you tried and why isn't it working? (Clearly you have tried things as you've been working on it for "5 days".) Also, I've removed your plea on stating it's ASAP; that won't endear the users here to answer you quickly, it's more likely to have the opposite affect. We use our free time to contribute on this site, so asking us to drop everything to help you goes down poorly. Thanks

Comment: The specific duplicate does not correctly answer this question.

Comment: @forpas if they've created a new account you should flag the post and provide a link in the custom flag to the old one; too often it's to avoid a question ban and that is against the rules of the site.

Comment: @Larnu I already provided the link and closed the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Larnu but somebody else reopened it!

Comment: That doesn't change my comment about that it should be have a custom flag created @forpas .

Comment: @Larnu maybe you know something that I don't. What do you mean by custom flag?

Comment: When you flag, there is an option for "requires moderator attention", and then you get be details about why. I have raised a flag now, as the OP's prior post was closed by a mod and reposting it on an alternative account is a clear example of over lap of accounts to avoid repercussions.

Comment: @Larnu . . . This now closed as a duplicate to a closed question that has an incorrect answer.  None of this is helping the OP.

Comment: It is an **exact dupe** @GordonLinoff . It's not about the answer it's that the OP has specifically reposted their exact question with no changes... Plus the fact that they have broken the rules of using an alternative account by them interacting (reposting a question closed by a mod on a separate account, probably due to a question ban, also isn't allowed).

Comment: The OP should be taking the time to make their original question clear using the edit feature, not reposting exact dupes, on a separate account.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I would suggest that you vote to reopen the other question, if that is your position.  The question was not an exact dupe before it was edited, because the data sample now is unambiguous on the intentions (I thought it was clear before but others might disagree).  The situations rests:  The OP has twice attempted to get a question answered and only generated a bunch of comments, closed questions, and inaccurate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select name, min(startime), max(endtime)
  From
(Select t.*,
       Sum(case when lgendtime between startime and endtime then 0 else 1 end) 
           over (partition by name order by starttime)  as sm
  from
(Select t.*,
       Lag(endtime) over (partition by name order by starttime) as lgendtime
  From your_table t) t) t
Group by name, sm
```

Comment: @nishant, I have updated the answer as in previous version I was taking lag starttime which should be actually lag endtime. Check now. It should solve your issue.